# What is the UTF-8 representation of "end of line" in text file

Tags: java, utf-8

what is the binary representation of "end of line" in UTF-8.

Comment: I asked Rabbi Google, and he said : 00001010

Comment: The end of line is platform specific, not encoding specific.  The UTF-8 encoding of end of line is the same as the ASCII values e.g. it could be 0x0D 0x0A (windows) or just 0x0D (Unix and Mac OS X)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [Unicode Character 'LINE FEED (LF)'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm)

> In UTF-8 (hex) its --> 0x0A (0a)
>   UTF-8 (binary) -->  00001010

[image]

Answer (score 54):

There are [a bunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode):

- `LF`:    Line Feed, [U+000A](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000A) (UTF-8 in hex: 0A)
- `VT`:    Vertical Tab, [U+000B](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000B) (UTF-8 in hex: 0B)
- `FF`:    Form Feed, [U+000C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000C) (UTF-8 in hex: 0C)
- `CR`:    Carriage Return, [U+000D](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000D) (UTF-8 in hex: 0D)
- `CR+LF`: CR ([U+000D](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000D)) followed by LF ([U+000A](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=000A)) (UTF-8 in hex: 0D 0A)
- `NEL`:   Next Line, [U+0085](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0085) (UTF-8 in hex: C2 85)
- `LS`:    Line Separator, [U+2028](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2028) (UTF-8 in hex: E2 80 A8)
- `PS`:    Paragraph Separator, [U+2029](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2029) (UTF-8 in hex: E2 80 A9)

...and probably many more.

The most commonly used ones are `LF` (*nix), `CR+LF` (Windows and DOS), and `CR` (old pre-OSX Mac systems, mostly).

Comment: Hex code for CR+LF is *not* 0x0D0A as shown in your answer. Instead, UTF-8 hex 0x0D0A refers to a Malayalam letter.

Comment: @manavm-n - The UTF-8 hex sequences shown above are *individual bytes*, not a single value (it's an **8-bit** encoding [with surrogate sequences so it can encode the full 21 bits of Unicode]). So that's 0D (13 decimal) followed by 0A (10 dec), not a single 16-bit value 0D0A (3338 dec). I've added spaces to make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 10):

UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII, so the ASCII codes 10 (0x0A) for linefeed and 13 (0x0D) for carriage return are also used in UTF-8.