# is it possible to include multi-line text field in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have been able to code solidity and have a single line text field for user inputs. Is it possible to include multi-line text field in solidity? I'd want the user to input a paragraph of information. Maybe more than just a paragraph.

Comment: Just commenting back on my own post...it might not be allows because the ledger isn't really made to keep all of that data. I think a better solution would be to have a document hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can store UTF-8 encoded data in `string` variables](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#simple-smart-contract), so you should be able to include multiline text as well, as that's just like any other text [but with line breaks in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836352/what-is-the-utf-8-representation-of-end-of-line-in-text-file):

> **Note**
>
> All identifiers (contract names, function names and variable names) are restricted to the ASCII character set. It is possible to store UTF-8 encoded data in string variables.